# Are private key and public key extracted from key pair are of same length using openssl

Tags: openssl, cryptography

when the below function is used to generate RSA key pair of 1024 bits.

```
rsa_key = RSA_generate_key ( 1024, 3, NULL, NULL );

keyPair = BIO_new ( BIO_s_mem ( ) );

PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keyPair, rsa_key, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

keyPair_len = BIO_pending(keyPair);
```

Then keyPair_len obtained is not 1024, it is 882.
what is the reason that it got reduced.

By using RSA_generate_key() function are we generating key pair or only private key.
If so when we extract private and public keys from that it is generating private and public keys of different lengths.

```
evp_key = EVP_PKEY_new();
ret = EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA ( evp_key, rsa_key );
pri = BIO_new ( BIO_s_mem ( ) );
pub = BIO_new ( BIO_s_mem ( ) );

PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey ( pri, evp_key, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL );
PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY ( pub, evp_key );

pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);
```

The lengths of pri_len pub_len are 916 and 272 respectively.
Can anyone help in understanding the reason why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

You generate a RSA key of modulus size 1024 **bits** and not **bytes**. The private key basically contains public key information so in any representation (be it DER or PEM) it will be larger.

The results you're obtaining are not these modulus sizes, but the sizes of their ASN.1 structure encoded in PEM. Even the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` stuff.

More on this here:
https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Comment: I'd like to add that it is not uncommon to use _unbalanced_ keys for RSA keypairs. What this means is that the public and private key doesn't have to be the same size. This gives you a trade-off in terms of speed: having a larger private key makes signing more computationally expensive than verifying the signature. The rationale behind this that you sign a piece of data once, but verification is usually performed more often. Given a large enough security margin, brute-force factoring of an unbalanced key shouldn't pose a problem either.